# Node module.exports reference own function like this keyword?

Tags: node.js, module, scope

I have the following code:

```
module.exports.functionA = function(str) {
     console.log(str);
}
```

In the same module, how do I call functionA? In other languages such as PHP, you can call another member of the same class using $this->functionA();

This does not work:

```
module.exports.functionA('Hello world!');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `functionA` was assigned to module.exports it was still undefined. Instead do:

```
var functionA = function(str) {
    console.log(str);
}

module.exports = {
    functionA: functionA
}
```

Then the following will work:

```
module.exports.functionB = function() {
     functionA('Hello world!');
}
```